# Passing FILEGROUP as PARAMETER when moving index to new filegroup

Tags: t-sql

How do i pass filegroup as a parameter

```sql
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mytable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [my_costraint] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

              [pzV] ASC,

              [pxZZZ] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 85) ON [need to pass filegroup as parameter here]
```

Comment: You'll need to dynamically build the SQL and `exec()` it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append filegroup dynamically while creating an index in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535174/how-to-append-filegroup-dynamically-while-creating-an-index-in-sql-server)